# Broken CSS on iPhone when using Twenty Thirteen wordpress theme

Tags: php, iphone, css, wordpress, stylesheet

I'm tweaking the default Twenty Thirteen Wordpress theme and have just made some CSS adjustments, in fact I've only added one class. When I check it on my phone the CSS won't show at all as if the link was broken. The site works good in desktop mode and is responsive and all there but not in the phone browser.

When I check my site on iPhone. It works well on everything except iPhone. When I use firebug to check the CSS is loading or not, I did not found the mail stylesheet on iPhone only.

I used Wordpress 3.6 and Twenty thirteen theme.

Comment: okay... so what's your question?

Comment: What color is this iPhone?